# Early return from a function which has a return type of [String] in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, swift-guard, fail-fast-fail-early

I have a function which returns an **Array** of **String** if some conditions are met. But I want to have the early return functionality in my function. Something like this:

```
func fetchPerson() -> [String] {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return nil
    }
    .......
    .......
}
```

But I'm facing issues like:

> Nil is incompatible with return type '[String]'

I tried writing only `return` statement. But it fails too. What to do?

**Edit: 1**

What if I just want to return back from this function without any value. Just back to the line where the call to this function happened. Something like:

```
func fetchPerson() -> [String] {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return //return to the line where function call was made
    }
    .......
    .......
}
```

Comment: return empty array  .. `func fetchPerson() -> [String] {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return []
        }
        
        return []
    }`

Comment: If I want to return back not with any value, then? @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: then check if fetchPerson().count > 0 or not and proceed further with your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solved this error two ways.

- Either change return type to `[String]?` from `[String]` means make
  return type optional.

  ```
  func fetchPerson() -> [String]? {
      guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
          return nil
      }
      .......
      .......
  }
  ```
- Either Change return statement to `return []` from `return nil` means
  return empty array.

  ```
  func fetchPerson() -> [String] {
      guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
          return []
      }
      .......
      .......
  }
  ```

Comment: What if I want to just return from the function when else condition meets? What if I want to write `return` only?

Comment: @nayem Then you can use `if let` instead of `guard let`.

Comment: No. What I meant to say is, **I want to return back not with any value**.

Comment: @nayem With `guard let` you need to call return and you have add that inside function which needs return type `[String]` so you have only two option with return as I have written or you can use `if let`. Also if your `return []` then it means your array is empty and if you use nil with optional then also it means you are not returning any value it is nil.

Comment: @nayem you might wanna look into optionals